# What does Skolem's paradox have to do with "unrelativized quantification"?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, quantifiers

Timothy Bays' excellent [essay on Skolem's paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-skolem/index.html#note-30) includes the following claim:

> ... Skolem's Paradox doesn't introduce contradictions into various forms of axiomatized set theory, even when these axiomatizations are themselves understood formalistically or model-theoretically. **From a proof-theoretic standpoint, for example, there is a difference between unrelativized quantification and quantification which has been explicitly relativized to some formula in our language** (where this formula is one that, from an intuitive perspective, serves to “pick out” the domain of countable model of ZFC). So, there's no *a priori* reason to think that a sentence with unrelativized quantifiers will conflict with that sentence's fully-relativised counterpart.

What does he mean by "relativized" or "unrelativized quantification" from a "proof-theoretic standpoint"? Later, in the same paragraph, he speaks about domain-restricted quantification, so it cannot be that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $V$ is our universe, and $A$ is a subset of that universe. We can relativise the formulas to $A$ by recursion:

1. If $\varphi(\vec x)$ is an atomic formula, then $\varphi^A(\vec x)$ is simply $\varphi(\vec x)\land\vec x\in A$. (Here $\vec x\in A$ is understood as the conjunction of $x_i\in A$ for the variables appearing in $\vec x$).
2. If $\varphi=\varphi_0*\varphi_1$ (or $\lnot\varphi_0$), then $\varphi^A$ is $\varphi_0^A*\varphi_1^A$ (or $\lnot\varphi_0^A$), where $*$ is any connective.
3. If $\varphi=\exists x\varphi_0(x)$, then $\varphi^A=\exists x(x\in A\land\varphi_0(x))$.

Of course, if $A$ is not definable, we need to add it as a predicate. We can deduce from this that $(\forall x\varphi(x))^A=\forall x(x\in A\to\varphi^A(x))$, assuming the logic we're working with is close enough to first-order logic.

The point is that since ZFC proves that $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, it proves "for all $x$, if $x$ is a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R$, then $x$ is not surjective". When we take a countable model of ZFC, the quantifiers (and the interpretation of $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb R$) all relativise to that model. That means that we simply have:

> For all $x$ **in the model**, if $x$ is a function from $\Bbb N$ *of the model* to $\Bbb R$ *of the model*, then $x$ is not surjective (*in the model*).

Note that we can have a reverse Skolem paradox: if ZFC is consistent, then it has a model $M$ such that $\Bbb N^M$ is uncountable (externally!).

Comment: Thanks Asaf. Bays' very next sentence begins "Similarly, from a model-theoretic perspective...". Would you say that your answer addresses the "model-theoretic perspective" or the "proof-theoretic standpoint"?

Comment: I'm neither a proof theorist nor a model theorist, so I can't quite answer that. But I'd imagine that the proof theoretic perspective is syntactic, that's the first part, and the second part is more model theoretic.